# Get value from JSON object having special character in key using SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have an outlet_details table having two columns(`id` and `extended_attributes` as a JSON object).
extended_attributes have values like

```
{
    "parent-0-0-id": "DS-606",
    "parent-0-1-id": "SD066",
    "secondaryOutletCode": "MG_918"
}
```

I want to get `parent-0-0-id`'s value, but when I'm trying to hit

`SELECT extended_attributes->>'$.parent-0-0-id' AS 'parent00id' FROM outlet_details;`

I'm getting an:

> invalid JSON path expression error(3143).

Comment: "->>" - Are you sure your DBMS is sql-server really?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just enclose the column name under quotes to separate out the name from escape characters.

`SELECT extended_attributes->>"$.\"parent-0-0-id\"" AS 'parent00id' FROM outlet_details;` should work